# does node js mysql needs apache

Tags: mysql, node.js, apache

I have recently wanted to use a MySQL database with my node.js server. And after doing some digging, I found the following github page for `mysql` to be used via `node.js`:

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql

However what I wasn't sure is if this is an API that allows for node.js to communicate with a MySQL database, or if this is a full implementation of a MySQL database (hence I wouldn't need to install apache). Since I tried implementing this without an apache server, it gave me an error:

code run (after having doing `npm install mysql`)

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'articles'
});

connection.connect();
```

error:

> [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306]

Comment: no, it doesn't need apache, but it needs mysql running. In your case on localhost.

Comment: oh so it is kind of an API that communicates with a MySQL server @AlexBlex? so would that mean that I could also communicate with a MySQL server if I change the `host` to something that isn't local host? and then not require to install mysql on my machine?

Comment: to some degree. It's a bit more complex. mysql has it own settings, and the best practice is to bind it to local or internal network interface. Keep it listening on public IP is considered insecure. The point is Mysql is a database, that runs by it own. You can connect to it from shell, nodejs, or a handful of other languages at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Apache" commonly refers to the [Apache `httpd`](http://httpd.apache.org) program and that's just a web server. You can use that in conjunction with your Node app, for example via [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com) to handle process management and load-balancing.

MySQL is a separate package, a database server, that must be running if you want to make use of MySQL in your Node code. The NPM package for MySQL is just a driver, it needs a server to connect to, and if one isn't running where it's configured to connect you'll see an error like what you're getting.

The solution here is to install MySQL server on your machine, or make use of an existing MySQL server you control.

Sometimes people confuse "Apache" with things like [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/) which bundle a bunch of things together.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js MySQL does not require Apache; however, make sure that you are running a MySQL server on your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Apache is a web server. MySQL is a database. You don't need either to use the other. But you do need a MySQL Server running on your localhost to use MySQL with Node.js, the github link you provided is like an API to use MySQL with Node.js.

Node.js has its own web server which you can use for development, however when and if you move to production, you would want to use a web server like Apache or Nginx with your application, and you will have to do some work for that. But you probably are just learning and won't do that anytime soon.